# Tri-state Kendo-Switch (for null values)

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Is it possible get a tri-state kendo-switch input to allow 3 states: true/false/null?

I need the user to be able to specify a true/false result and also the option to specify they wish to use whatever the global default is for the option they are ticking.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not possible. The reason is very simple: this is not how switch should work. Switch is just mobile-friendly checkbox. So the easiest way is probably to add another switch that will show/hide previous one or to develop component yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it doesn't exists. But there is request to implement this feature. Check it [here](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-feedback/suggestions/20383852-undefined-switch-state-aka-3-states).